# Dart eventloop control equivalent

Tags: dart

In NodeJS we have `process.nextTick()`, `setImmediate` and `setTimeout` , I want to know what is equivalent in Dart

> `setImmediate()` is designed to execute a script once the current poll phase completes.
> `setTimeout()` schedules a script to be run after a minimum threshold in ms has elapsed.

> any time you call `process.nextTick()` in a given phase, all callbacks passed to `process.nextTick()` will be resolved before the event loop continues. This can create some bad situations because it allows you to "starve" your I/O by making recursive `process.nextTick()` calls, which prevents the event loop from reaching the poll phase

Comment: I have no knowledge about NodeJS so I am not entirely sure what you are looking for. But it looks like microtask: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/scheduleMicrotask.html

Comment: If that is not the case, could you provide an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: Yes, I saw the same article but since Dart is not the same as NodeJS, you cannot assume you can make a 1-to-1 conversion of your NodeJS program to Dart. So that it why I asked if you could give an example of what you want to achieve (the problem you want your program to solve) and not just a description of API calls.

Comment: I am using `bloc` in my flutter app when I `add` and event it not change state synchronously, in another part  of app that executed synchronously in call stack after `add` , I need to read the `state` value but it is not changed due to synchronously execution, I added a `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` to break synchronously , I want to be sure its a good way and there is no alternative

Comment: `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` does not make any synchronously break.

Comment: it works, because next lines are executed in next loop of the eventloop

Comment: Yes, but you cannot call it synchronously break since you code will be inside a method which are now returning a `Future` since the method are now asynchronously. But you problem sounds more that you should pack your `state` inside a `Future` object or make it a `Stream` you can subscribe to changes.

Comment: In general, it is bad design to make it as a dependency that "I guess the variable are properly set if I just wait for the event queue to be empty". Instead, you should make you code so you can actively depend on the `state` being set to a value.

Comment: I think `Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` is equivalent to `setTimeout((){},0)`, I want to know is there any other equivalent for `setImmediate` and `nextTick`

Comment: You can e.g. use a `Completer` to create a `Future` which you are given a value at a later point in time: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Completer-class.html

Comment: You are right, I am aware, But I asked something else!

Comment: Yes, you asked for something else but what you asked for is considered bad software design and you are going to have "a bad time" with Dart if you want the same guarantees as NodeJS provides in this area since it is two very different runtime environments. So there are no directly 1-to-1 translation in Dart for the NodeJS features but there are some which have similar behavior. I can write that as an answer but I also knows that the consequences of this would be... A lot of programmers thinking they can make 1-to-1 conversion of NodeJS programs without thinking about the small details. :)

Comment: @julemand101 I exactly know what you are taking about and I am 100% agree that ` it is bad design to make it as a dependency that "I guess the variable are properly set if I just wait for the event queue to be empty"`, I am aware, If you know more about my question let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding Dart operations are:

- `setTimeout(callback, durationMS)`: [`Timer(duration, callback)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Timer-class.html) or [`Future.delayed(duration, callbackWithResult)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html).
- `setImmediate(callback)`: [`Timer.run(callback)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Timer/run.html), `Timer(Duration.zero, callback)` or [`Future(callbackWithResult)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Future/Future.html).
- `nextTick(callback)`: [`scheduleMicrotask(callback)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/scheduleMicrotask.html) or [`Future.microtask(callbackWithResult)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-async/Future/Future.microtask.html).